# Error when using Roboteq Controller ROS2 driver

Tags: ros2, ros-control, driver

I have roboteq Controller for brushless DC Motor.  I would like to use the driver abd the controller with ROS2 humble. I was  using this fork https://github.com/DoanNguyenTrong/roboteq_controller_ros/tree/galactic-devel to build it with ROS2 humble but got error in ./controller_driver/src/roboteq_controller_ros/roboteq_controller/include/roboteq_controller/roboteq_controller_node.h in line 26 #include "nav_msgs/msg/odometry.hpp". So can not find the header for the nav_msgs. But when just comment the line it works. So my question is do we need the header or how to fix it if need it?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 
Installing the dependencies such as `nav_msgs` can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error you are getting is because humble has different dependencies.

I wrote a ROS2 foxy driver last year that I recently added humble dependencies to. Might work with your MC.

check out the humble branch of

https://github.com/CJdev99/roboteq_ros2_driver/tree/humble-dev

Haven't tested with hardware but you can give it a go.

Comment: I got the Error.[roboteq_ros2_driver]: serial::IOException: 
[roboteq_ros2_driver-1] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'serial::IOException'
[roboteq_ros2_driver-1]   what():  IO Exception (2): No such file or directory, file /home/ros2_roboteq/src/serial-ros2/src/impl/unix.cc, line 151.
[ERROR] : process has died [pid 242752, exit code -6, cmd '/home/ros2_roboteq/install/roboteq_ros2_driver/lib/roboteq_ros2_driver/roboteq_ros2_driver --ros-args -r __node:=roboteq_ros2_driver --params-file ros2_roboteq/install/roboteq_ros2_driver/share/roboteq_ros2_driver/config/roboteq.yaml'].

Comment: ros2 run roboteq_ros2_driver roboteq_ros2_driver 
[INFO] [1705381865.450158384] [roboteq_ros2_driver]: Opening serial port on /dev/motor_controller at 115200...
[WARN] [1705381865.450433976] [roboteq_ros2_driver]: serial::IOException: 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'serial::IOException'
  what():  IO Exception (2): No such file or directory, file /home/omni/ros2_roboteq/src/serial-ros2/src/impl/unix.cc, line 151.
[ros2run]: Aborted

Comment: I think I saw the same error when the USB port was wrong.. Maybe try removing the udev rule for the controller and use the assigned port.

It could also be another plethora of issues.. I originally wrote it for foxy and tested it with a controller and it worked, just recently changed some things to work with humble. The serial library is also outdated, could be something in that as well

Comment: from https://answers.ros.org/question/240535/ros-serial-exception-missing-file/:
" 
Look for your device with ls /dev. If none of the entries match the one you are calling when running your nodes, this error message will appear.
"

Comment: when ls /dev the port appear  ttyACM0 . But still same error

Comment: what do you mean by 'Maybe try removing the udev rule for the controller and use the assigned port." ?

Comment: found the error. In the  src file driver_dev.cpp line 74 should be driver_dev.cpp  should be         port = this->declare_parameter("port", "/dev/ttyACM0");. Also in the config file the  baud: 230600 but the driver_dev.cpp its   baud = this->declare_parameter("baud", 115200);.. How can I decrease the motor speed. I tested and its crazy high

Comment: Oh ok, that block of code was meant so you can update those values at runtime. Maybe I'll just take that out entirely.

Are you running in open loop? I would try decreasing max_amps and max_rpm

Comment: Actually, if you are not using a gearbox, change the GEAR_RATIO in roboteq_ros2_driver.hpp to 1 as well.

Comment: Im running in with SLAM, slam_toolbox and using 2D Lidar and 3D Camera with 9 axis IMU. So robot got feedback. So decreasing the  max_amps and max_rpm will decrease the speed right?

Comment: what do you mean by  not using a gearbox? what is  GEAR_RATIO parameter for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150921/discussion-between-chase-and-macedon971).

Comment: ok. im in the chat

Comment: sorry one more question. Why the map is twisted when run the mobile robot around? Can we have a discussion in chat?

Comment: Sure, join that link above.

Comment: hi @Chase texted you in chat. Pls check